# Bee email composer integration (alternative to Mosaico)

Tags: extension, email, mosaico

Has anyone had experience with using [Bee](https://beefree.io/) with Civi? I see that Nicolas Ganivet, the co-founder and CTO of Cividesk, was [looking into it](https://help.beefree.io/hc/en-us/community/posts/207322905-BEE-Plugin-in-CiviCRM) back in 2016.

In my opinion, Bee has significant advantages over Mosaico. I realize Mosaico is open-source and free, but its capabilities and user interface seem to be lacking compared to Bee.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The mosiaco extension integrates the mosaico editor for mass e-mail editing in CiviCRM. However it is not an e-mail service.

I dont know of anyone in the community who have been looking into it, however there is a question on Stack Exchange about integrating a bee template into CiviCRM: [CiviMail/Cron Fails using BeeFree template](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/civimail-cron-fails-using-beefree-template)